# QUiLoader cast from QWidget* to QDialog*, possible?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qt5

It seems I'm missing something here. Shouldn't be possible to cast from QWidget to QDialog?

```
QUiLoader loader;
QFile file("../../plugin/ui/settings.ui");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
m_settingsDialog = qobject_cast<QDialog*>(loader.load(&file));
if(!m_settingsDialog)
    qDebug() << "invalid!";
file.close();
```

I keep getting it invalid.

Comment: Did you check that ```loader::load``` doesn't return null in the first place? I don't see that here.

Comment: Yes, I checked, `loader::load` works fine. Replacing `QDialog` by `QWidget` works. But I want it to be modal, so I think QDialog should be used, right? And when `exec()` is called program crashes. If, instead, `show()` is called, then it works.

Comment: I think the problem might actually be that ```loader::load``` internally creates a ```QWidget``` object, and returns a pointer. If you cast it to a ```QDialog*```, which is a _subclass_ of ```QWidget``` you're basically doing an illegal downcast. You have to make sure that ```loader::load``` actually creates a ```QDialog```object internally. I _assume_ this can be done in the definition file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your `settings.ui` file doesn't describe a `QDialog`, because the loader doesn't create one (hence the dynamic cast failure).

If you control the ui file and are the only user, you can change it to define a `QDialog`.

If you don't, you can embed the loaded widget in a `QDialog`:

```
m_settingsDialog = new QDialog;
QWidget settingsWidget = loader.load(&file);
settingsWidget.setParent(m_settingsDialog);
```